# Show-Command of commandlet with pre-filled parameters

Tags: powershell

Have written a function in powershell with parameters. Would like to use cmdlet `Show-command` to show UI of the function. But my troubles are to show the function with already pre-filled parameters of my function.

This works well:

```
Show-Command Get-ChildItem
```

What I need is:

```
Show-Command Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\windows"
```

So the UI of the cmdlet `Get-ChildItem` should have pre-filled the path parameter of Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

I understand that "-Path" is not a parameter of `Show-Command` and therefore it doesn't work. But is there any idea or workaround?

Have been trying also to use the the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` like this:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"Get-childitem:Path" = 'c:\windows'}
Get-ChildItem
```

this lists the Windows directory correctly, but next command:

```
Show-Command Get-ChildItem
```

does not pre-fill the parameter of Path to c:\windows

Comment: It sounds to me like what you want to actually do is use comment based help to add examples to your function, so that someone could do `get-help your-function -examples` and see how to use it with example values.

Comment: The background is to save the paramaters somewhere and then later 1day/1 month load the parameters and prefill the show-command and maybe change only one parameter and run the command again and save the new parameters with modified one parameter

Comment: @LumirJ. `Show-Command` in Windows PowerShell does not have this capability. Next version of PowerShell is likely to have a re-implementation of `Show-Command` that works cross-platform, so it might be worth opening an issue on GitHub to get this functionality in the future

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, `Show-Command` (as well as `Out-GridView`) is WPF-based and WinForms and WPF support in .NET Core 3.0 won't be cross-platform, it'll be Windows-only: see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/

Comment: @mklement0 You're right. Still worth a feature request for Windows in PowerShell 7 though :)

Comment: Show-Command is not a valid cmdlet in PowerShell 6+.

And , the above behavior is expected, Show-Command is a UI way of using a cmdlet. Nothing will be pre populated. When using default values, it is identified and used after command invocation. Here you can click on Run button and hit enter, you'll get the desired behavior.
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9974